# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Philosophy Stack Exchange](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Are all fallacies created equal?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7858/are-all-fallacies-created-equal)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [How does Popper overcome this critique?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7914/how-does-popper-overcome-this-critique)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is there a name for each individuls perceived sphere of reality?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8041/is-there-a-name-for-each-individuls-perceived-sphere-of-reality)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Does something require its opposite in order to be defined?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/does-something-require-its-opposite-in-order-to-be-defined)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Is contemporary advertising a form of Rhetorics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8039/is-contemporary-advertising-a-form-of-rhetorics)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [What is the difference between Fact and Truth?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/what-is-the-difference-between-fact-and-truth)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Are there any listings of Plato's dialogues in internal chronological order?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/are-there-any-listings-of-platos-dialogues-in-internal-chronological-order)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [St. Thomas Aquinas' Contingency Proof for the Existence of God](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7899/st-thomas-aquinas-contingency-proof-for-the-existence-of-god)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)
- [What does it mean for an axiom to be logical?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/what-does-it-mean-for-an-axiom-to-be-logical)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What are the limitations of Hegels Dialectic that Schelling identified?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/what-are-the-limitations-of-hegels-dialectic-that-schelling-identified)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

Comment: There's a lack of consensus here. A couple of questions show a distinct split between reviewers, half of them thinking the question is great, half of them thinking it sucks. We need to figure out the direction the site should take if we want new users to not feel lost.